How to make a dc motor ramp up/down
I am a model railroad hobbyist and enjoy dabbling in electronics. I would  like to build a small circuit that will let the DC motor that pulls a locomotive take several seconds to reach full rpm. Also I'd like it to take an approximately equal time to slow down when powered off. It would look more like a real train.
Here is a short attempt I tried.  I put a capacitor across the terminals of a motor. The capacitor charges when the motor is running and it does provide current once shut off. So this could work to "slow down" the train. But I was hoping the charging of the capacitor would lengthen the time the motor takes to reach full speed, and it does not.
I experimented with a few diodes but couldn't come up with a way to slow the startup.  Any ideas?
By the way, I know that most high-end trains nowadays have high tech electronics (DCC) that can achieve this  but I prefer to build with discrete components. It's more fun that way.


Ready made solutions using DCC are readily available everywhere. You can set ramp-up and down speeds etc..

OP states:  >By the way, I know that most high-end trains nowadays have high tech electronics (DCC) that can achieve this but I prefer to build with discrete components. It's more fun that way.

Typically that could be done with a PWM circuit that slowly varies the duty-cycle up and down.
Would you be interested in building such a circuit, requiring one simple IC and a few resistors, capacitors, and a diode and MOSFET.

Yes that would be very helpful to see

With the large C as shown, when you close the switch, you'll get a very large current charging the C, and this will mean there is no slow ramp of V when starting. You may also damage the switch with such a large current.
If you put a resistor in series, this will limit the rate of rise in voltage and will help. However, the resistor will also limit the maximum current the motor can consume.
Take an n-channel MOSFET, connect drain to the power source; source to the motor//capacitor. Connect a 10 uF capacitor from gate to ground, 1 MΩ from gate to the switch (other end of the switch at 12V), and 100k from the switch to ground.
This R.C circuit will make the FET's gate drive slowly (about 10 s rising as described, 11 s falling), and the source will follow about 2 V lower, thus slowing the motor. You don't need (don't want) the 100 mF.
At the end, the FET will have about 2 V loss across it; depending on motor current, and heat sinking,this might cause excessive power dissipation.

Looks great - are you able to post a circuit diagram so I can be sure I interpret your text correctly?
